# change the text of a label and in js and use it from code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, string, label

I created a list of buttons from code behind, and  append them on some div, how ever each button has an onclick java script function 
here is how I did it:

```
string[] messages = CM.GetMessages(Session["USER_EMAIL"].ToString()).Split(new string[] { "$STARTCHAT$" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string[] usersalone =  CM.GetChaters(Session["USER_EMAIL"].ToString()).Split(new string[] { "$NEWUSER$" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string[] username = CM.GetUserNames(Session["USER_EMAIL"].ToString()).Split(new string[] { "$NEWUSER$" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            for (int i = messages.Length-2; i>=0; i--)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.ID = Session["USER_EMAIL"].ToString()+username[i];
                b.Text = "Chat With: " + usersalone[i] ;
                b.Width = 250;
                b.Height = 100;

                b.OnClientClick = "return DisplayMessage('" + messages[i+1] + "','" + username[i] + "','" + Session["USER_EMAIL"].ToString() + "')";
                b.Style.Add("background-color", "rgb(246, 246, 246)");
              //  lblChatwith.Text = username[i];
                NewMsgNotArrow.Controls.Add(b);
            }
```

and here is my java script function:

```
    function DisplayMessage(messages, from, username) {
    document.getElementById("AllMessages").innerText ="";
    document.getElementById("DivDisplayMessage").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("lblChatwith").innerText = from;
    var MessageForEachUser = messages.split("$SAMECHATNEWTEXT$");

    for (var i = 0; i < MessageForEachUser.length; i++)
    {
        var ck = MessageForEachUser[i].indexOf("$" + from.toUpperCase() + "$") > -1;

        if (ck == true) {
            document.getElementById("AllMessages").innerText += from.toUpperCase() + ":\n";
            var temp = MessageForEachUser[i].split("$" + from.toUpperCase() + "$");
            MessageForEachUser[i] = temp[0];
        }
        if (ck == false) {
            document.getElementById("AllMessages").innerText += username.toUpperCase() + ":\n";
            var temp = MessageForEachUser[i].split("$" + username.toUpperCase() + "$");
            MessageForEachUser[i] = temp[0];
        }
        document.getElementById("AllMessages").innerText += MessageForEachUser[i] + "\n______________________________________________________" + "\n";
    }
    return false;
}
```

every thing is working well but, when i want to use one of the labels like "lblchatwith" from code behind it return an empty string.

Comment: Come on! How are we supposed to help you with this kind of problem description? We can just _guess_. Please post the related code!

Comment: sorry, just 1 min I'll change the question

Comment: @Vohuman, I hope that will help

Comment: Is lblchatwith created dynamically from code behind? Could you also show the definition of lblchatwith in your code.

Comment: no it's not from code behind just a normal tag 
 `<strong><label style="margin-left:150px;margin-top:20px">You are chatting with: </label><asp:Label ID="lblChatwith" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong>`